# ¿Cómo puedo llamar a una función de una clase derivada desde el main?

Tags: c++, punteros, clase, puntero-a-función

Tengo tres clases, una base (`Vehiculo`) y otras dos derivadas(camión y coche). En el programa principal quiero pedir los datos según que tipo de vehículo tenga y crear un objeto en un vector de punteros a vehículo llamado `miGaraje` dependiendo del tipo que sea.

```
class Vehicle
{
public:

    Vehicle();
    virtual void Display();         
    virtual void Set_Data(string p, int y);
    string GetPlate();
    virtual ~Vehicle();

protected:
    int year;                   //year of manufacture
    string plate;               //licence plate

};

class Car :public Vehicle
{
public:
    Car();
    void Set_Data(string p, int y, char malet, int horsepower);
    void Display();
    void PrintMaletero();
private:
    int hp;
    string maletero;
};

class Lorry :public Vehicle
{
public:
    Lorry();
    void Set_Data(string p, int y, int load);
    void Display();
private:
    int lmax;
};
```

Para establecer los datos tengo una clase `Set_Data` en cada clase derivada, mi problema viene aquí. ¿Cómo llamo a cada función dentro de mi clase derivada dependiendo del tipo de vehículo que tenga?

En el `main` tengo esto para que el usuario indique el tipo de vehículo e ir a la función donde pido los datos (siendo `myGarage` lo siguiente `vector<unique_ptr<Vehicle>> myGarage;`):

```
cout << "\n\t Vehicle type is Car(c) or Lorry(l)?:  ";
            cin >> opClass;
            if (opClass == 'c' || opClass == 'C') {

                unique_ptr<Vehicle> p_theVehicle(new Car);
                DataIn(opClass);//, *p_theVehicle);
                myGarage.push_back(std::move(p_theVehicle));                
            }
```

Y siendo esta la función donde pido los datos, creo el Coche o Camión (en el ejemplo esta para coche) y donde tengo el problema al llamar a la función `Set_Data`:

```
void DataIn(char Opt)//, Vehicle *p_theVehicle)
{
    int m_year = 0, m_lmax = 0, m_hp = 0;
    string m_plate = "null";
    char m_maletero = 'm';

    cout << "\n Year of the vehicle? : ";
    cin >> m_year;
    cout << "\n Plate? : ";
    cin >> m_plate;

    if (Opt == 'c' || Opt == 'C') {
        cout << "\n Horsepower? : ";
        cin >> m_hp;
        cout << "\n Maletero grande (G) o pequeño(P) ? : ";
        cin >> m_maletero;
        unique_ptr<Vehicle> p_theVehicle(new Car);
        p_theVehicle->Set_Data(m_plate, m_year, m_maletero, m_hp);


    }
    else if (Opt == 'l' || Opt == 'L') {
        cout << "\n Maximum Load? : ";
        cin >> m_lmax;

    }

}
```

¿Cómo puedo llamar a `Set_Data` del Coche? El programa me llama al `Set_Data` de `Vehiculo` y me dice que tengo demasiados argumentos de entrada.

Y cómo preguntas adicionales:

¿Crearías `p_theVehicle` dentro o fuera de la función `DataIn`?¿En caso de fuera luego cómo pasarías el puntero a la función `DataIn`?¿El `push_back` del vector `myGarage` lo harías dentro o fuera de la función?

Answer (score 1):

```
  unique_ptr<Vehicle> p_theVehicle(new Car);
  p_theVehicle->Set_Data(m_plate, m_year, m_maletero, m_hp);
```

Con este código, lo que el compilador sabe es que `p_theVehicle` está apuntando a una instancia de `Vehicle`; no sabe si esa instancia es un `Car` o `Truck` así que no te deja usar a un método que no `Vehicle` no tiene definido.

Opción A:

```
  unique_ptr<Car> p_theCar(new Car);
  p_theCar->Set_Data(m_plate, m_year, m_maletero, m_hp);
```

Ahora sabe que `p_theCar` tiene los métodos de `Car` disponibles.

Opción B:

```
  Car *car = new Car();
  car->setData(m_plate, m_year, m_maletero, m_hp);
  unique_ptr<Vehicle> p_theVehicle(car);
```

Por supuesto, si siempre vas a hacer un `setData`, igual te conviene pasar los datos por el constructor de `Car`.

Answer (score 1):

**Opción 1: Pasar los parámetros en el constructor**

Esta solución es bastante útil cuando los valores no van a cambiar después de la inicialización

```
class Vehicle
{
public:
    Vehicle(string p, int y);
};

class Car : public Vehicle
{
public:
    Car(string p, int y, char malet, int horsepower);
};

class Lorry :public Vehicle
{
public:
    Lorry(string p, int y, int load);
};

Vehicle::Vehicle(string p, int y)
  : plate{p},
    year{y}
{ }

Car::Car(string p, int y, char malet, int horsepower)
  : Vehicle{p,y},
    hp{horsepower},
    maletero{malet}
{ }

Lorry::Lorry(string p, int y, int load)
  : Vehicle{p,y},
    lmax{load}
{ }

std::unique_ptr<Vehicle> v1 = std::make_shared<Car>("123",2018,'C',180);
std::unique_ptr<Vehicle> v2 = std::make_shared<Lorry>("123",2018,30000);
```

**Opción 2: Crear métodos que permitan modificar los valores**

En vez de tener un método `Set_Data` se disponen varios *set* individuales. La ventaja de este sistema es que normalmente no necesitas métodos virtuales:

```
class Vehicle
{
public:
  void SetPlate(string p)
  { plate = p; }

  void SetYear(int y)
  { year = y; }
};

class Car : public Vehicle
{
public:
  void SetMalet(char malet)
  { maletero = malet; }

  void SetHorsepower(int horsepower)
  { hp = horsepower; }
};

class Lorry :public Vehicle
{
public:
  void SetLoad(int load)
  { lmax = l; }
};

std::shared_ptr<Car> newCar = std::make_shared<Car>();
newCar.SetPlate("123");
newCar.SetYear(2018);
newCar.SetMalet('C');
newCar.SetHorsepower(180);

std::shared_ptr<Vehicle> vehicle = newCar;
```

**Editado**

En base a los cambios que has puesto en la pregunta, te cuento.

En el mismo momento en el que el usuario introduce la opción del vehículo a crear tu ya sabes que pasos hay que seguir, si es un coche hay que pedir unos datos y si es un camión otros.

Una posible solución:

```
std::unique_ptr<Vehicle> NewCar()
{
  string plate;
  int year, hp;
  char maletero;

  cout << "\n Year of the vehicle? : ";
  cin >> year;
  cout << "\n Plate? : ";
  cin >> plate;
  cout << "\n Horsepower? : ";
  cin >> hp;
  cout << "\n Maletero grande (G) o pequeño(P) ? : ";
  cin >> maletero;

  return std::make_unique<Car>(plate,year,maletero,hp);
}

std::unique_ptr<Vehicle> NewLorry()
{
  string plate;
  int year, lmax;

  cout << "\n Year of the vehicle? : ";
  cin >> year;
  cout << "\n Plate? : ";
  cin >> plate;
  cout << "\n Maximum Load? : ";
  cin >> lmax;


  return std::make_unique<Lorry>(plate,year,lmax);
}


cout << "\n\t Vehicle type is Car(c) or Lorry(l)?:  ";
cin >> opClass;
unique_ptr<Vehicle> vehicle;
if (opClass == 'c' || opClass == 'C')
  vehicle = NewCar();
else if( opClass == 'l' || opClass == 'L' )
  vehicle = NewLorry();

myGarage.push_back(std::move(vehicle));
```